# how to read the pop server response in python

Tags: python

I am trying to read the response or exception of pop3 hotmail server. its very simple question but i am beginner in python don't know how to read it? this is my code:

```
import poplib
import sys
host = 'pop3.live.com'
port = 995
email='123456@hotmail.com'
pwd='123456'
server = poplib.POP3_SSL(host, port)
try:
    server.user(email)
    server.pass_(pwd)
    if('+OK'):
        print 'Email: '+email+'password: '+pwd
        server.quit()
        sys.exit(1)
except poplib.error_proto:
    if('POP+disabled'):
        print 'Email: '+email+'password: '+pwd
        server.quit()
        sys.exit(1)
    elif('authentication+failed'):
        print "wronge user and pass. try again"
        continue
    continue
```

in exception "if ('POP+disabled')" used to eliminate that user login and password is correct but the account has not enabled POP3 in options.

when I run the above code then it also display email password whether i put wrong password...

Can any body help me please how to handle this problem?

Comment: I think you're missing something here `if('+OK'):` always returns true since bool of a string as always true unless its empty. You need to have a proper condition. `if something == "+OK"`

Comment: I think it's `response = server.pass_(pwd)`

Comment: Barmar I had check this command to... but not working... don't save the response in this way

Comment: Ashoka Lella >> that's what i actually mean.. but i don't know how to save this response in variable... i had tried all method but fail

Answer (score 0):

You can use the server.getwelcome() method to check for the server response before proceeding into parsing messages.

The server object lets you request the list of messages after authentication and then you can call retr to retrieve each message.

```
    welcomeresp = server.getwelcome()
    if welcomeresp.find("+OK"):
       numMessages = len(server.list()[1])
       for i in range(numMessages): 
          for j in server.retr(i+1): 
              server_msg, body, octets = j
              for line in body:
                 print line
```

Take a look at the documentation for the POP library for more information and an example:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/poplib.html

Comment: I had check all commands server.retr(), list(), _getresp() etc.. but can't able to save the response in a variable :(

Comment: I modified my answer to show how to store the message in a variable "body"

Comment: Sir my problem is not to store the message.... my problem is to store the response... if you will check my program again... then the program you show .... that step is needed after authentication passes and when user login... but in my program i want to store response before user login

Comment: I think you are looking for the getwelcome() method. I modified my answer.

Comment: You can check the welcome message before authentication